# CSS Hover Change Unhovered Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make some trick with hover but i am stuck at one point. What I want to do is when I hover on one of "nav-link" I want to change unhovered ones.

For example when I come on to "HOME" I want that the other nav-links' font-weight turn to light.

Here's my html;

```
<div class="nav-bar">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">RESUME</a>
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
</div>
```

I believe it can be done either with css or jquery but i am stuck. Thank you for you help.

Comment: What about the default / active state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one more way to get that using pseudo-selector `:not`
So it gets less css-code

```css
.nav-bar a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav-bar:hover a:not(:hover) {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">RESUME</a>
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hover on the div and hover on the anchor

```css
.nav-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav-bar:hover a {
  color: #CCC;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #0F0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">RESUME</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">CONTACT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly now, much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: when adding hover on child no need to add hover on parent, when hovering a child you are obliged to hover the parent, so hover on child is enough, the last can be `.nav-bar a:hover`